# Trim text (with CSS?) in highscores template

Tags: css, ellipsis, texttrimming

I'm building a highscores page template, 
And would like to trim the username (ideally with CSS) if the username and/or score is too long.
See this picture :

[image: highscores page template]

I can use

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow-y:none;
```

To trim the username, but how can I trim it relatively to the score length ?

Have you got an idea of how doing this ?
Here's a Codepen of my current code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yymZGM

Thanks

Comment: can you use display:flex; in your project?

Comment: You should really use tables to display tabular data. I know a lot of web developers think tables are pure evil, but this is exactly what they're useful for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the score span (which is floated right) before the name

Updated [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/WbVPmx)

```css
#highscores {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
#highscores .round {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0.4em 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow-y: none;
}
#highscores .round .round-index {
  padding-right: 2%;
}
#highscores .round .round-author {
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 60%;
}
#highscores .round .round-score {
  width: 28%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="highscores" class="celio-black">
  <p id="round-4" class="round">
    <span class="round-score">75</span>
    <span class="round-index">01</span>
    <span class="round-author">grosbouff</span>

  </p>
  <p id="round-1" class="round">
    <span class="round-score">75486987</span>
    <span class="round-index">02</span>
    <span class="round-author">I have a super long name isn't it ?</span>

  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, you need a `<table>`, so that way more simple:

**HTML**

```
<table id="highscores" class="celio-black">
  <tr id="round-4" class="round">
    <td class="round-index">01</td>
    <td class="round-author">grosbouff</td>
    <td class="round-score">75</td>
  </tr>                            
  <tr id="round-1" class="round">
    <td class="round-index">02</td>
    <td class="round-author">I have a super long name isn't it ?</td>
    <td class="round-score">75486987</td>
  </tr>                                              
</table>
```

**SCSS**

```
#highscores {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    .round {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        height: 1.2em;
        position: relative;
        background-color: red;
        padding: 0.4em 0;
        .round-index {
            padding-right: 2%;
        }
        .round-author {
            font-weight: 700;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            overflow-y: none;

        }
        .round-score {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ahhg6p38/1/)**

```
.round {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    height:1.2em;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.4em 0;
    overflow-y:none;
}
.round-index {
    padding-right: 2%;   
}
.round-author {
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background-color:red;  
    display:inline-block;
}
.round-score {
    width: 28%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;    
    max-width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background-color:green;  
    display:inline-block;
}
```